# DaggerApplicationComponent Unresolved Reference

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dagger-2

I'm trying to apply DaggerApplicationComponent in MVVM architecture by modifying MVP app, Belajar App, but I've just got error of Unresolved reference: DaggerApplicationComponent. Kotlin kapt has been applied and I've tried to rebuild project, but instead I got error from application component:
C:\Users\3\AndroidStudioProjects\belajar3 - Copy (3)\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\id\kotlin\belajar\di\component\ApplicationComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<id.kotlin.belajar.BelajarApp> {
^
retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.HomeModule.providesHomeDatasource(retrofit)
id.kotlin.belajar.data.HomeDatasource is injected at
id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeViewModel(datasource)
id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeViewModel is injected at
id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.HomeModule.bindHomeViewModel(viewModel)
java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
id.kotlin.belajar.di.factory.ViewModelFactory(viewModels)
id.kotlin.belajar.di.factory.ViewModelFactory is injected at
id.kotlin.belajar.di.builder.ActivityBuilder.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeActivity.viewModelFactory
id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeActivity) [id.kotlin.belajar.di.component.ApplicationComponent ? id.kotlin.belajar.di.builder.ActivityBuilder_ContributeHomeActivity.HomeActivitySubcomponent]

I need suggestion for this problem. Thank you.

This is the code:

ApplicationComponent:

```
import dagger.Component
import dagger.android.AndroidInjector
import dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjectionModule
import id.kotlin.belajar.BelajarApp
import id.kotlin.belajar.di.builder.ActivityBuilder
import id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.Networkmodule
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, Networkmodule::class,
    ActivityBuilder::class
])
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<BelajarApp>
```

BelajarApp:

```
import dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject
import dagger.android.AndroidInjector
import dagger.android.DaggerApplication
import id.kotlin.belajar.di.component.DaggerApplicationComponent


class BelajarApp : DaggerApplication(){
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication>? {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.create().apply { inject(this@BelajarApp) }
    }
}
```

My github repo:

https://github.com/muhammadwibisonojanuar/Coding-2.git

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your HomeModule you need a Retrofit dependency.

```
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun providesHomeDatasource(retrofit: Retrofit): HomeDatasource=
            retrofit.create(HomeDatasource::class.java)
```

But there is no method like:

```
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit() : Retrofit {
       //Return Retrofit here
    }
```

**Create the above method and it will all work.**

As you can see in your NetworkModule you only provide a Builder, but you do not actually build it:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesHttpAdapter(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit.Builder {
        return Retrofit.Builder().apply {
            client(client)
            baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about applicationcomponent? which occurs error retrofit cannot be provided?

Comment: About returning retrofit. What kind retrofit do I have to return? Where do I have to provide the provideRetrofit

Answer (score 0):

Since I really don't know about using Kotlin, only follow it, I think I need your opinion about it.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).